# Conformal map from Circles to annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question:

> Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be two Euclidean circles in the plane with $C_2$ lying in the interior of $C_1$. Let $\Delta$ be the domain bounded by these circles. Is there a conformal map of $\Delta$ bijectively onto an annulus $\{z: 0<r_1 < z < 1 \}$?

I am really not sure. I know that the Riemann Mapping Theorem involves mappings of simply connected domains, but an annulus is not simply connected.

---

The comments are suggesting an affirmative answer. I am wondering whether the following sequence of maps works:

By performing a translation and dilation, we may assume that $C_1$ is $|z| = 1$. Then, the inverse of the mobius transformation

$$\frac{z-i}{z + i}$$

maps the circle $C_1$ onto the real line and maps the interior to the upper half plane. Since the circle $C_2$ is contained in $C_1$, we see that $C_1$ is a circle somewhere in the upper half plane. Thus, the region $\Delta$ is the upper half plane minus some disk.

Now, translate the disk by a real constant so that the center is on the imaginary axis. After this translation say that center of $C_2$ is now $c = ri$ where $r > 0$.

Now, apply the mobius transform

$$\frac{z - c}{z + c}$$

This maps the real line to the circle $|z|=1$ and maps the circle $C_2$ to circle in $\mathbb{D}$ (that is centered at $0$)

Comment: This is true - see the list in this article on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) or this mathoverflow question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11182/riemann-mapping-for-doubly-connected-regions.

Comment: actually one can arrange the map to be a Mobius transform here since you just need to find an automorphism of the disc $D_1$ bounded by $C_1$ that sends $C_2$ to a circle concentric to $C_1$ as then a translation of the centers to the origin and a homothety to make the bigger radius $1$ finalize your problem (the automorphisms are Mobius and they always send circles inside to circles inside, so you just need to show that you can get a concentric circle and that can be done either using standard formulas for the images of circles under Mobius transforms or by a geometric continuity argument

Comment: @Conrad does the following argument in my edit make sense?

Comment: looks good and I agree that having at one's disposal translations makes life easier here (working directly in the unit disc one can show that you can move the center to be the origin but one needs a bit of hyperbolic geometry or computations)

Comment: If $K_1$ (the image of $C_1$ under the original map from the disc to the upper half-plane) has center $(a,b), b>0$ and euclidean radius $q>0$, note that $b >q$, hence there is $c>0$ s.t $c^2b^2=c^2q^2+1$; doing first $z \to cz$ your construction works since a euclidean circle centered at $di$ of radius $r$, is a hyperbolic circle centered at $i\sqrt {d^2-r^2}$ so if that is $i$, it gets sent back to a hyperbolic circle centered at the origin, but that is also an euclidean circle centered at the origin too since the lines through the origin are geodesics in both geometries in the unit disc